# Show that continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ are Borel-measurable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Here are my thoughts. We want to show that $f^{-1}$ maps Borel sets to Borel sets.

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function and $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ a Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $B$ open. Then $f^{-1}(B)$ is open as well, that is, there exists neighborhoods around every point of $f^{-1}(B)$ contained within. Since these neighborhoods are members of $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, their union are also members of $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Hence $f^{-1}(B)$ is a member of $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

Here's where I'm stuck. I don't know how to show countably many such members can have their unions taken to give me $f^{-1}(B)$. I also don't know what to do with the closed sets in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, especially singletons and those only generatable via complements.

Hints?

Comment: You do know $f^{-1}(\cup B_i)=\cup f^{-1}(B_i)$.  And same for unions and complements.  Inverses respect all three operations.

Comment: @GregoryGrant I did not know this! This is kind of an important result I never learned or even considered. Well now my question is very trivial, uh...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This relies basically on the fact that inverse functions respect all three set operations: arbitrary unions, arbitrary intersections and complements.  In other words $f^{-1}(\cup B_\alpha)=\cup f^{-1}(B_\alpha)$, $f^{-1}(\cap B_\alpha)=\cap f^{-1}(B_\alpha)$ and $f^{-1}(A^c)=(f^{-1}(A))^c$.  All three of these are pretty easy to prove.  Incidentally functions going forwards only respect unions, while inverse is much better behaved.

Comment: your argument has a gap. How do you still show that the inverse image of a general borel measurable set is measurable? One has to use something like the good sets principle like Henricus and then use your observation. It won't simply follow from your observation.

Answer (score 11):

You need to establish the following lemma:

> Let $(X,\Sigma),(Y,\mathrm{T})$ be measurable spaces. Suppose that $\mathrm{T}$ is generated by $\mathcal{E}$. A mapping $f:X \to Y$ is $(\Sigma,\mathrm{T})$-measurable if and only if $$\forall E \in \mathcal{E}, f^{-1}[E] \in \Sigma$$

Proof: The only if part is trivial. For the other direction, observe that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set $\{S \subseteq Y\mid f^{-1}[S] \in \Sigma\}$ contains $\mathcal{E}$, so it also contains $\mathrm{T}$.

By substituting $\Sigma,\mathrm{T}$ with the Borel sets, and $\mathcal{E}$ with the open sets (a.k.a. topology) on $\mathbb{R}$, the proof is complete.

Answer (score 0):

One thought that helped me understand the statement, and may be useful is:

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function and $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ a Borel $\sigma$-algebra. The ($b$,+$\infty$) is an open set (It can be written as $\cup^{\infty}_{n=1}$B($x_0$,$\epsilon$$_x$)) therefore ($b$,+$\infty$)$\in$ $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Then [-$\infty$,$b$] = $\mathbb R$$\setminus$($b$,+$\infty$) = ($b$,+$\infty$)$^c$$\in$ $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ (because it is a $\sigma$-algebra).

We already know that $f$=continuous and [-$\infty$,$b$] = closed $\in$ $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ $\Rightarrow$ $f$$^{-1}$([-$\infty$,$b$]) = closed $\in$ $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and since* [$f$ $\leq$ $b$] = $f$$^{-1}$([-$\infty$,$b$])$\in$ $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ then the "$f$", by definition, is Borel-measurable.

PS1:* [$f$ $\leq$ $b$] = $f$$^{-1}$([-$\infty$,$b$]) = {$x$$\in$$\mathbb R$: $f(x)$ $\leq$ $b$}.