# Proving that the function $x^2$ is a Borel function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, borel-sets

How should I prove that the function $x^2$ where $x^+=\max(x,0)$,  $x^-=-\min(x,0)$  and $|x|=x^+ + x^-$ is a Borel function?

I know that a Borel function is a random variable $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. But how to mathematically prove it? I have no idea... May be I should use indicators? But how?

Comment: Not answered but this question has useful tips in the comments.

Comment: An easier thing to do might be to prove that all continuous functions are Borel, thus the results for all the functions you mention will follow

Comment: @Gâteau-Gallois Isn't this kind of cyclic though ? To show continuity he must show that the pre image of any open set is an open set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is borel $\iff \; \forall B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) : f^{-1}(B)  \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \iff \; \forall b \in \mathbb{R} :  f^{-1}(-\infty,b) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).$

$$ f^{-1}((-\infty,b)) = \{x : x^2 \in (-\infty,b) \} = \{ x : x^2 < b \}$$

If $b < 0 :$ then $\{ x : x^2 < b \} = \varnothing.$

If $b \geq 0$ then

$$ x^2 < b \iff - \sqrt b < x < \sqrt b.$$

So $$ f^{-1}((-\infty,b))= \begin{cases} \varnothing &\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})  & b < 0 \\ (-\sqrt b, \sqrt b)& \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) & b \geq 0\end{cases}$$
and $f$ is borel.

Consider $f(x) =  \vert  x \vert.$ Let $b \in \mathbb{R}$:

1. If $b < 0$:

$$ f^{-1}(-\infty ,b) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = \vert x \vert < 0\} = \varnothing$$

Since the empty set is an open (closed) it is a borel set so $ f^{-1}(-\infty ,b) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \in \forall b < 0$.

2. if $ b \geq  0:$

$$ f^{-1}(-\infty ,b) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = \vert x \vert < b\} = (-b,b)$$

Since $(-b,b)$ is an open set it is a borel set and $ f^{-1}(-\infty ,b) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \in \forall b \geq 0.$

Comment: Where did you take into consideration $|x|=x^++x^-$?

Comment: @Atstovas I didn't. I thought I'd only do one. Are you having trouble for $\vert x\vert$ ?

Comment: Yesss... accually I new how to show that $x^2$ is Borel function. But I didn’t know what to do with given conditions

Comment: Which given conditions ? For $ f = \vert x \vert$  you should do exactly the same show that $f^{-1}(-\infty,b)$ is a borel set for all $b$. You're making me doubt if you even understood the solution for $f = x^2$. Are you sure you understood that one ?

Comment: @Atstovas I've edited my answer. Any questions ?

Comment: Yes, I prove it, bet I split it to 3  sets : when $b<0$, $b=0$ and $ b>0$. I thoght I need to take all other conditions.. so I don’t know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to run the details with $x \to x^2$, I suggest that you take a look at this
[Show that continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ are Borel-measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654046/show-that-continuous-functions-on-mathbb-r-are-borel-measurable)

Probably though, it would be smarter to really understand the answer given in this link, and thus to be able to show that this holds for any continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$, which includes the case you are looking for.